# Moment Generating Function of a squared Gaussian R.V.

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, moment-generating-functions

I have a question to why the pdf has only an $x^2$ term and not an $x^4$ term in computing the MGF of the squared gaussian mgf:

$$E[e^{tX^2}]
= \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{tx^2}\tfrac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}dx
= \tfrac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(1-2t)x^2/2}dx
= \tfrac1{\sqrt{1-2t}},$$

I needed to compute the chi squared expectation and variance and always came up with the wrong answer.
Now I found the solution, which goes through the same steps I did, but it has the x term squared and I'm completely at a loss why it's not $x^4$.

The reasoning I went to $x^4$ is that I just treated $x^2$ as a variable itself and plugged it into the standard normal pdf.
I am assuming my mistake lies here? Would you be kind enough to explain why though?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Your reasoning is not clear. The calculation done above is an application of this theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician.

Comment: @StubbornAtom I apologize, I found that one earlier but I still have the same question. I'm sorry for being a bit slow here. I had presumed that the pdf of the squared standard normal variable is just the same pdf with where $x$ is replaced with $x^2$ as this is just another random variable, this is how I came up with x^4 as the pdf of the normal squares the variable (and so $(x^2)^2$)?

Comment: That's not how it works; $Y=X^2$ is another random variable with a distribution of its own. So you can instead find the distribution of $Y$ and then calculate $E[e^{tY}]=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{tx}f_Y(x)\,dx$ where $f_Y$ is the pdf of $Y$.

Comment: Oh, or take the second derivative of the MGF of the standard normal ? Thank you for your patience!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how it works: if $X$ is a continuous random variable on $\mathbb{R}$ with density $f$, and $g$ is some measurable function, then $g(X)$ has expectation

$$ \mathbb{E}[g(X)] = \int_{\mathbb{R}}g(x)f(x)~\mathrm{d}x.$$
Here we apply this with $g(x):= e^{tx^2}$.

Comment: Hi, thank you, but why isn't the density using an $x^4$ term instead of the squared term?